# Simple Way to Duplicate and Mirror Points on a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Is there a simple way to duplicate and mirror the points on a UIBezierPath?

My current solution creates a duplicate of the whole path, transforms it and then appends it to the working path. It works, but it seems cumbersome.

```
let duplicatePath = UIBezierPath()
duplicatePath.append(path)
duplicatePath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -rect.origin.x, y: -rect.origin.y))
duplicatePath.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1))
duplicatePath.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: rect.origin.x + rect.width, y: rect.origin.y + rect.height))

path.append(duplicatePath)
```

Comment: I guess the question is - why are you trying to duplicate things? I'm sure you could duplicate the points in an array - provided you know the arcs between the points. But that's seems.... wrong to even think to do. So maybe you are trying to create the same path? Turn things into a `CALayer` or one of it's subclasses and get it's `.path`. Still, what is the *real* issue you are facing?

Comment: So in this specific instance, I'm building a shape that I want to be symmetric. Specifically its the [squiggle line in the SET game](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Set-game-cards.png). I created a path using addCurveToPoint that represents half the squiggle, and now I want to duplicate and inverse that path to complete the shape. The code above achieves that goal, but my question is whether there's a way to do the same thing without creating a second object instance.

Comment: So the word you should use - and please, I'm not arguing - is *simpler*. You have a way to do it, right? But if *feels* wrong? To be honest, I think you have the correct way! It not only works, it doesn't seems to be costly in terms of (at least at the level of code posted) CPU cycles, memory, anything.

Comment: Okay, cool! I'm still learning from online sources, so it helps to have the feedback. Thanks!